# Creating named set

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a named set that would return sum of selected members for any measure. When I deploy I am getting error

> function expects a tuple set expression for the argument. A string or
>   numeric expression was used.

Please review my code and suggest solution. I have a dimension named Uline and this named set should sum selected 4 members of this dimension for any measure

```
    sum({[Uline].[CU - (46)],
         [Uline].[FRU - (45)], 
         [Uline].[GL - (38)],
         [Uline].[PU - (44)]},[Measures].CurrentMember)
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `Aggregate` rather than `Sum` if you wish it to be available for any measure.

Also no need to include the `Measures` hierarchy inside the function.

So try something simpler like this:

```
Aggregate(
  {
   [Uline].[CU - (46)],
   [Uline].[FRU - (45)], 
   [Uline].[GL - (38)],
   [Uline].[PU - (44)]
  }
)
```

Please note though that this will be a new member in an existing hierarchy, like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Uline].[AggSet] AS
  Aggregate(
    {
     [Uline].[CU - (46)],
     [Uline].[FRU - (45)], 
     [Uline].[GL - (38)],
     [Uline].[PU - (44)]
    }
  ) 
SELECT
  [Measures].[SOMEMEASUREinCUBE] ON 0,
  [Uline].[AggSet] ON 1
FROM [CubeName];
```

I don't play around with the actual cube scripts myself but I'd guess the above could be implemented like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.Uline.AggSet  AS 
     'Aggregate(
        {
         [Uline].[CU - (46)],
         [Uline].[FRU - (45)], 
         [Uline].[GL - (38)],
         [Uline].[PU - (44)]
        }
      )'
```

If you'd rather create a custom set than a calculated member then try the following:

```
CREATE SET CURRENTCUBE.[AggSet]  AS 
        {
         [Uline].[CU - (46)],
         [Uline].[FRU - (45)], 
         [Uline].[GL - (38)],
         [Uline].[PU - (44)]
        }   
 ,
 Display_Folder = 'Sets';
```

The curly braces `{}` mean `SET` in mdx.

In the context of a script this looks like the following:

```
WITH SET [AggSet] AS
    {
     [Uline].[CU - (46)],
     [Uline].[FRU - (45)], 
     [Uline].[GL - (38)],
     [Uline].[PU - (44)]
    }
SELECT
  [Measures].[SOMEMEASUREinCUBE] ON 0,
  [AggSet] ON 1
FROM [CubeName];
```

Comment: I want to avoid creating a calculated member, as it shows up in Uline hierarchy, and then messes up totals as all the members that I am using for the Aggregate get duplicated.

Comment: I tried the script that you suggested to create a named set (With member  [Uline].[AggSet] AS...) and I get build error "Syntax for with is incorrect". Not sure if we can use it in mdx expression for the named set.

Comment: I think The problem with my original expression is that it is not a tuple. How do I make it a touple?

Comment: @user1689992 `set tuples` and a `set` are effectively the same. If you do not wish to create a calculated member then I will add the syntax for creating a straight `set`. There will be no need to Aggregate or Sum if you don't want a calculated member